# compare the value of same items with one exception case

Tags: perl

A,food,75

B,car,136

A,car,69

B,shop,80

A,house,179

B,food,75

C,car,136

ECX5,flight,50

QC4,train,95

C,food,85

B,house,150

D,shop,80

EAX5,flight,50

QA4,train,75

F,movie,

It should do comparison between the values of same type (wherever the 2nd column matches) and Print the differ .Now i want output to look like:

**A,food,75 is not matching with B,food,75 C,food,85

A,car,69 is not matching with C,car,136 B,Car,136

A,house,179 is not matching with B,house,150

QC4,train,95 is not matching with QA4,train,75

F,movie missing value

---

Code I've written is below but its not printing the format the way I want.

```
  while (FILE) {
   my $line = $_ ;
   my @lines = split /,/, $line ;
   $data{$lines[1]}{$lines[0]} = $lines[2] ;
   }

 foreach my $item (keys %val) {
  foreach my $letter1 (keys %{$val{$item}}) {
 foreach my $letter2 (keys %{$val{$item}}) {
  if ( ($val{$item}{$letter1} != $val{$item}{$letter2}) && ($letter1 ne 
     $letter2) &&  ( (!defined $done{$item}{$letter1}{$letter2}) || 
     (!defined 
   $done{$item}{$letter2}{$letter1}) ) ) {
     print "$item : $letter1, $val{$item}{$letter1}, $letter2 , 
     $val{$item}
   {$letter2}\n" ;
     }


 }
```

Comment: here is the code I've written its working but not printing the output in the format i want.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: I've spent some time reformatting your code to make it easier to follow. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in future.

Comment: You seem to have deleted half of the code!

Comment: And now you've undone all the work I did tidying your code. If you can make your code legible, then I might have another look. But until you do, I've lost interest.

Answer (score -1):

Really hard to follow the logic of your code.
But I seem to get the desired result with this:

[Edit] The code was edited as per the comments

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my (%hash, 
  );
while(my $line=<DATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  my ($letter, $object, $number)=split /,/, $line;

  ###  here we are dealing with missing values
  if ($number =~ m{^\s*$}) {
    print $line, "missing value\n";
    next;
  }

  ### here we dissever exceptional items apart from the others 
  if ($letter=~m{^E[AC]X\d$}) {
    $object = "exceptional_$object";
  }

  $number+=0; # in case there is whitespace at the end
  push @{$hash{$object}{$number}}, [$letter,$number,$line];
}

for my $object(sort keys %hash) {
  my $oref = $hash{$object};
  if (1==keys %$oref) {
    next;
  }
  my $str;
  for my $item (values %$oref) {
    $str .= $str ? " $item->[0][2]" : "$item->[0][2] is not matching with";
  }
  print ($str,"\n");
}


__DATA__
A,food,75
B,car,136
A,car,69
B,shop,80
A,house,179
B,food,75
C,car,136
ECX5,flight,50
ECX4,train,95
C,food,85
B,house,150
D,shop,80
EAX5,flight,50
EAX4,train,75
F,movie,
```

**output**

```
F,movie,missing value
A,car,69 is not matching with B,car,136
EAX4,train,75 is not matching with ECX4,train,95
C,food,85 is not matching with A,food,75
A,house,179 is not matching with B,house,150
```

What the algorithm does:

Looping through the input we remember the all the lines for each unique pair of object and number.
After going through the input loop we do the following:
For each object we skip it if it has no different numbers:

```
if (1==keys %$oref) {
    next
}
```

If it has, we build an output string from a list of the *first remembered lines* for that object and number (that is we omit the duplicates for the object and number);
the first item from the list amended with "is not matching with".

---

<sub>Also, I am reading from the special filehandle DATA, which accesses embedded data in the script. This is for convenience of demoing the code</sub>

Comment: Thanks @wolfrevokcats I tried this but when I'm adding one matching case in the input for that also it's printing  see below case added for shop

Comment: @Sonal please edit your question, add the matching case and the expected result there

Comment: in case of shop, its saying not matching in the output while the values for the shop are same ( B,shop,80 & D,shop,80)

Comment: @Sonal can you clarify, why `A,food,75  is not matching with B,food,75 C,food,85` -- is ok to output, and    `B,shop,80  is not matching with D,shop,80` -- is not?

Comment: as all the values in food sections are not matching irrespective of letters (A, B,C)so this case is okay. but in second case B,shop,80 is not matching with D,shop,80 this should not come in output as both values in shop case are matching with each other (irrespective of letters B,D)

Comment: @Sonal I've updated my answer. It's not in the same order as  your data, but I guess that's irrelevant?

Comment: @Sonal I've edited the answer, but I think it's the last time. Those are insignificant changes to the algorithm; you could have actually easily figured it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks @wolfrevokcats